# Could not determine the dependencies of the COM reference "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

I'm trying to run a project I loaded which uses `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.
I've installed the `Primary Interop Assemblies` and the `bootrap` as well for Officer 2010 (as installed).
I had Office 2013 which I uninstalled and reinstalled Office 2010.
I've added the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` through the `COM` references tab.
Afterwards I've deleted the `1.8` excel version from the Registry as mentioned here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/dd052f27-20d6-4b6b-9d8b-fe4fd9c6b9fc/broke-excel-interop-com-assembly-after-installingremoving-2013-beta-release?forum=exceldev
I've restarted the computer, and still I get the warning above and also :
`Could not determine the dependencies of the COM reference "VBIDE". Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)`

I've understand I should add the references using the .NET tab and not COM tab, but there is no .NET tab in the references window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using VS2012, you should see the Interop references under `Assemblies -> Extensions`:

[image]

The result is a .NET reference that looks like this:

[image]

**Update:**
As mentioned [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6be2fc73-04a4-4219-a583-414b5a084d97/could-not-find-microsoftofficetoolsexcelextensions-namespace), ensure you have the full VSTO installed (not just the runtime):

[image]

Comment: How do I get this to appear in the 'extensions' tab ? There is not `Office` reference in there at all.